# wix msi version number 5th digit

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to give 5th digit for version number in windows installer. If I give

**Source**

< Product Id="ECD80D85-E2F4-4995-A48C-23E2EA5CAD19" Name="Services" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0.001" Manufacturer="test" UpgradeCode="0de21488-400e-4b79-8be1-3acd2d633e4a">

and compile its throwing

**Error 1 The Product/@Version attribute's value, '1.0.0.0.001', is not a valid version. Legal version values should look like 'x.x.x.x' where x is an integer from 0 to 65534.**

How to implement this

Comment: Can you provide the piece of your code that's throwing the error?

Comment: < Product Id="ECD80D85-E2F4-4995-A48C-23E2EA5CAD19" Name="Services" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0.001" Manufacturer="test" UpgradeCode="0de21488-400e-4b79-8be1-3acd2d633e4a">

Comment: That's out of bounds for the Windows Installer ProductVersion. For some products I build, the requirement is to display an arbitrary string as the product version; The ProductVersion then becomes about as important as a DLL version. I register the real product version where it can be read for AboutBoxes. I hide the "Add/Remove Programs" entry that Windows Installer creates, make a visible copy of it and  set its DisplayVersion to the real product version.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think it should be even more restrictive.  [ProductVersion property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is defined as:

> The value of the ProductVersion property is the version of the product
>   in string format. This property is REQUIRED.
>
> The format of the string is as follows: major.minor.build The first
>   field is the major version and has a maximum value of 255. The second
>   field is the minor version and has a maximum value of 255. The third
>   field is called the build version or the update version and has a
>   maximum value of 65,535.

Rob must have decided that M.M.B.P 0-65535 for all four fields was good enough for XSD / compilation validation.  There is no way around this.

Comment: They also say

`Note that Windows Installer uses only the first three fields of the product version. If you include a fourth field in your product version, the installer ignores the fourth field.`

Comment: Very true and I point that out when people have issues with Major Upgrades leaving two versions in Add/Remove Programs.  But it isn't relevant to this question because the question was about adding a 5th field which the WiX XSD Schema won't allow.